# Section Header Titles incorrect

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have been trying to set the `uiTableViewHeader` for my `UITableView` for a couple of days now with no luck. I don't think I am far off. Currently it shows the section Titles however multiples the number of records by X amount ( I presume my count may be wrong).

I think I need to further configure my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method but Im unsure how.

I am a bit confused. I need to group the rowsAtIndexPath to the sections and stop them multiplying.

[image]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"atozCell";

 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

 if (cell == nil) {
 cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
 }

//Searchbar code is here

    NSDictionary *dataDict = [self.sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    cell.textLabel.text = [dataDict objectForKey:@"Title"];
}
 return cell;
}
```

**Section Counts**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.sectionArray count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.sectionArray objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

**Data Populated from**

```
 // Find out the path of recipes.plist
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"law2" ofType:@"plist"];

    // Load the file content and read the data into arrays
    self.dataArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];

    //Sort the array by section
    self.sortedArray = [self.dataArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[
                    [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Section" ascending:YES],
                    [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Title" ascending:YES]]];

    //Section for sorting
    self.sectionArray = [self.sortedArray valueForKeyPath:@"Section"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Always you are sending index of the object. So please try to use this one

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return [self.tableDataIndexTitles objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Comment: that is for section indexes not for my actual issue

Comment: Where did you implement this method  -(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

Comment: Updated above and removed `sectionForSectionIndexTitle` as that was only for testing something prior